# JSON automatic header in python

Tags: python, json

I have matrix nXn.

I want to save it on JSON file like that:

sample matrix:

```
12  1
3   4
```

sample JSON:

```
{'1-1': '12','1-2': '1','2-1': '3','2-2':'4'}
```

I want to create automatic header for NXN matrix like shown before and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: How are you storing your matrix at the moment?

Comment: @OP, are you sure you want the values to be strings too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import collections

data = [ [ 12,1], [3,4] ]
dataDict = collections.OrderedDict()

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    for j in range(0, len(data[0])):
        key = str(i+1) + '-' + str(j+1)
        dataDict[key] = data[i][j]

dataJson = json.dumps(dataDict)
print dataJson
```

Comment: got error:     json_dict[str(i) + '-' + str(j)] = str(matrix[i][j])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @hila You defined json_dict as a list. It has to be a dict to use strings as keys. You have to use the solution as-is or modify it correctly